# How to delete a specific digit from a number written on JLabel in JAVA?

Tags: java, swing, cursor, jlabel

If i have written a number on a JLabel in java, how can I delete a specific digit from it? Is there any option by which I can get the current Cursor position or set it as required and then delete a particular digit of my choice? Kindly help...

Comment: Could you please provide the code example?

Comment: Use a `StringBuilder`, use the text from the `JLabel` to seed it with, use `StringBuilder#delete` to delete the character at the specific location, use `StringBuilder#toString` to apply the result to `JLabel` - `JLabel` is not a "editable" component the user can edit

Comment: *String.replace("2","");*

Comment: I actually tried making a calculator in which the results are displayed on a JLabel. When I click on the "←" button, i need to delete the last digit from the JLabel..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just delete the last char of the labels text, which is a String, if you are not sure if that String can be null in some cases, catch a NullpointerException.

But always ensure, that the text is not empty when you call substring to prevent a IndexOutOfBoundException:

```
String text = jLabelObject.getText();
try{
    if(!text.isEmpty()){
        jLabelObject.setText(text.substring(0, text.length()-1);
    }
}catch(NullPointerException e){
    jLabelObject.setText("");
}
```

Please take a look at the Java API Doc

1. substring(), isEmpty(), length()[String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)
2. setText() [JLabel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html)

Comment: In what way does this answer differ from mine?

Comment: The only difference is, when the String is null, it is set to an empty one. And it uses a try catch for exception handling. It's mostly a matter of taste.

Answer (score 2):

You say you want to delete the last digit:

```
String txt = jLabel.getText();
jLabel.setText(txt.substring(0, txt.length()-1));
```

This should do the trick.

**Edit:**

You should also check for null or empty text:

```
String txt = jLabel.getText();
if(txt != null && !txt.isEmpty()) {
    jLabel.setText(txt.substring(0, txt.length()-1));
}
```